# How to transfer state through Link in react-dom 5.0?

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, react-router-dom

I develop react-app for the first time in my career.

So, I wander about a lot of things...haaa

I try to pass state between componet through Link element

But I did typing another variable syntax.

But I always see state: null on the console.

And There are many error message 'can't read state'

```
<Link to={{pathname:"/movie-detail", state:{year:year, title:title, summary:summary, poster:poster, genres:genres}}}>~~~</Link>

<Link to={"/movie-detail"} state={{year:year, title:title, summary:summary, poster:poster, genres:genres}}>~~</Link>
```

But I can't move state recipient component.

Please teach me that what is wrong with my code...

**Hading over code.**

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './Movie.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Movie({year, title, summary, poster, genres}){
    return (
        <div className="movie">
            <Link to={"/movie-detail"} state={{year:year, title:title, summary:summary, poster:poster, genres:genres}}>
            <img src={poster} alt={title} title={title}/>
            <div className="movie__data">                
                <h3 className="movie__title" style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>{title}</h3>
                <h5 className="movie__year">{year}</h5>
                <ul className="movie__genres">                  
                    {genres.map((genres, index) => {
                        return (
                        <li key={index} className="movie__genre">{genres}</li>
                        );
                    })}
                </ul>
                <p className="moive__summary">{summary.slice(0,180)}...</p>
            </div>
            </Link>
        </div>
    );    
}


Movie.propTypes = {
    id:PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    year:PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    title:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    summary:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    poster:PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    genres:PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
}

export default Movie;
```

**Recipient Code**

```
import React from 'react';
class Detail extends React.Component{
    
    componentDidMount(){
        
        const{location, history} = this.props;
        //console.log(this.props);
        if(location.state === undefined){
            history.push('/');
        }
    }
    
    render() {  
        const{location} = this.props;                      
            if(location.state){
                return(            
                    <span>{location.state.title}</span>
                    );
                }else{
                    return null;
                };    
    }    
}



export default Detail;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Link` component has a `to` prop which can be `string`, `object` and `function`. So the correct code is:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/movie-detail', state: { year: year, title: title, summary: summary, poster: poster, genres: genres } }}>~~~</Link>
```

Try using [withRouter](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) HOC wrap your `Detail` component so that you can get the `location` and `history` objects from the props.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using your router to pass data.
Ideally you'll want to fetch data from within your details page based off of the given route
`(e.g. /movie/star-wars fetches data for post "star-wars" from your server)`. By separating your router and component logic you maintain your application's modularity.